# Converting Timezone In Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe in format (store_id, day, start_time_local, end_time_local)which looks like this

```
1481966498820158979 0   "00:00:00"  "00:10:00"
1481966498820158979 0   "11:00:00"  "23:59:00"
1481966498820158979 1   "00:00:00"  "00:10:00"
1481966498820158979 1   "11:00:00"  "23:59:00"
1481966498820158979 2   "00:00:00"  "00:10:00"
1481966498820158979 2   "11:00:00"  "23:59:00"
1481966498820158979 3   "00:00:00"  "00:10:00"
1481966498820158979 3   "11:00:00"  "23:59:00"
1481966498820158979 4   "00:00:00"  "00:10:00"
1481966498820158979 4   "11:00:00"  "23:59:00"
1481966498820158979 5   "00:00:00"  "00:10:00"
1481966498820158979 5   "11:00:00"  "23:59:00"
1481966498820158979 6   "00:00:00"  "00:10:00"
1481966498820158979 6   "11:00:00"  "23:59:00"
```

The timezone for this dataset is local, I want to convert it to utc

This is the function I wrote
not handling overflows into dates properly

```
# Define a function to convert local time to UTC and handle day change
def local_to_utc_with_day(row, timezone_string):
    timezone_obj = pytz.timezone(timezone_string)
    local_start_time = timezone_obj.localize(row['start_time_local'])
    local_end_time = timezone_obj.localize(row['end_time_local'])
    
    utc_start_time = local_start_time.astimezone(pytz.UTC)
    utc_end_time = local_end_time.astimezone(pytz.UTC)
    
    # Check if the day has changed due to timezone shift
    if utc_start_time.date() != row['start_time_local'].date():
        row['day'] += 1
    
    row['start_time_utc_formatted'] = utc_start_time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')  # UTC time in HH:MM:SS format
    row['end_time_utc_formatted'] = utc_end_time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    row['start_time_local'] = local_start_time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')  # Keep HH:MM:SS format
    row['end_time_local'] = local_end_time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')  # Keep HH:MM:SS format
    return row
```

Comment: Did you take a look at [tz_convert](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.tz_convert.html)?

Answer (score 1):

IIUC:

Fake Data:

```
import pandas as pd
import pendulum


data = {
    "store_id": [1, 2, 3, 4],
    "day": [0, 0, 1, 1],
    "start_time_local": ["00:00:00", "11:00:00", "00:00:00", "11:00:00"],
    "end_time_local": ["00:10:00", "23:59:00", "00:10:00", "23:59:00"]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
```

Code:

```
cols = ["start_time_local", "end_time_local"]
tz = pendulum.now().timezone_name

for col in cols:
    df[col] = df.apply(
        func=lambda x: pd.to_datetime(arg=x[col], format="mixed").tz_localize(tz).tz_convert("UTC").tz_localize(None),
        axis=1
    )
print(df)
```

Output (my local time):

```
      store_id  day    start_time_local      end_time_local
0         1     0    2023-08-08 07:00:00  2023-08-08 07:10:00
1         2     0    2023-08-08 18:00:00  2023-08-09 06:59:00
2         3     1    2023-08-08 07:00:00  2023-08-08 07:10:00
3         4     1    2023-08-08 18:00:00  2023-08-09 06:59:00
```